# IOIO-OTG connect PC udev rules for linux fails to detect

Tags: linux, udev, ioio

The rules file is called 50-ioio.rules and the the text is:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYMLINK+="IOIO%n", MODE="666"
```

I copied this file to the udev rules directory using:

```
sudo cp 50-ioio.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
```

I then restarted udev using:

```
sudo restart udev
```

However when I connect the IOIO board via a USB cable and look for the serial port with

```
ls /dev/IOIO*
```

It is not being created? I cant find any errors in syslog or anything in dmesg or lsusb - I suspect the udev string is wrong but it is in the documentation for the device?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the whole box and it got discovered, its not the real answer but at least I can progress

Comment: it takes a few seconds to detect the IOIO in dev